# Does Xserver work like Pulseaudio?

Tags: linux, macos, audio, mouse

Ive ran to some problems understanding how does X server work. Here are my questions:
1)I know how Pulseaudio works, it takes input from several applications and make one output to ALSA(for example). But is X server doing the same? Does it take inputs from X clients(keyboard, mouse and monitor) and then gives certain inputs to corresponding drivers?
2)What is the relationship between stuff that is in /dev/input and X server?
3)Does X server draw the application?
Sorry if my questions sound silly. Hope you can help. Thanks.

Comment: Keyboard and mouse are not clients but input devices. The monitor most certainly isn’t an input device either.

Comment: Can every application that needs input/output of keyboard(for example) be called X clients?